# master.info File Continually Truncated

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration

I have a master-to-master replication setup on two different servers that are hosting MySQL Ver 14.14, Distrib 5.1.16 on Red Hat Linux. When I reboot one of the servers, the slave does not start. When I perform a listing of the /var/lib/mysql directory, I notice that the master.info file is truncated to zero length which causes MySQL to believe that replication is not setup.

Here is the my.cnf for server 1:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer  = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log-bin = mysql-bin
relay-log = mysqld-relay-bin
relay-log-index = mysqld-relay-bin.index
server-id = 101
binlog-format = STATEMENT
replicate-do-db = foo
replicate-do-db = bar
binlog-do-db = foo
binlog-do-db = bar
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 1
master-connect-retry = 2
sync_binlog = 1
log-error = mysqld.log
log-warnings = 2
wait_timeout = 31536000
expire_logs_days = 45
```

And here is the my.cnf for Server 2:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer  = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log-bin = mysql-bin
relay-log = mysqld-relay-bin
relay-log-index = mysqld-relay-bin.index
server-id = 102
binlog-format = STATEMENT
replicate-do-db = foo
replicate-do-db = bar
binlog-do-db = foo
binlog-do-db = bar
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 2
master-connect-retry = 2
sync_binlog = 1
log-error = mysqld.log
log-warnings = 2
wait_timeout = 31536000
expire_logs_days = 45
```

I setup the slave on each server like so:

```
STOP SLAVE ; RESET SLAVE ; CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='other_sys', MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='super_secret_password', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=14048 ;
```

The MASTER_LOG_FILE and MASTER_LOG_POS are just arbitrary in the above example. After doing this, I get the following for the MySQL slave status:

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: other_sys
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 2
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 14048
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 251
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: foo,bar
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 14048
              Relay_Log_Space: 407
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then perform a reboot of the server using the command `reboot`. After it reboots, the MySQL slave will sometimes start automatically from where it left off. Other times, the MySQL slave will not start at all and I notice that the `show slave status \G` returns an empty set and the /var/lib/mysql/master.info file is truncated to zero length. It is almost as if Linux is not flushing the file buffer to the inode on reboot so the slave information does not get saved.

Am I missing something when it comes to configuring the slave?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wants to know how I fixed this:

The issue was Linux file buffering. I performed the same steps above except I called `sync` right before I called `reboot` and it worked 100% of the time on ten attempts. Without `sync`, it failed 9 out of 10 times in my tests. I do not know why Linux is not syncing the file cache on shutdown but calling `sync` or waiting for one minute before issuing `reboot` has fixed the issue.

Comment: That's bizarre. The `shutdown` script on Unix was doing three or four `sync`s 35 years ago.

Comment: This actually turns out to be a bigger problem with our production systems. Turns out it does this with any and all files on our Linux system. I posted the problem on this site but it is being moved to the unix.stackexchange.com site. Maybe someone there can tell me if there is some configuration that our shop did to break this.